# How to write a function to get the max weight for the patients in a column for a duration of 3 weeks?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a column in my database which has the weight of patients from their first counselling to their last counselling.The details of each counselling is in a different record.
Suppose a patient's weight was 50 in the first 3 weeks, 51 in the next 3 weeks and 48 in the next 3 weeks. I want to write a python function which compares 50 with 51 and gets the max value of that in this case its 51 and again the function has to compare 51 with 48 and get the max value. This has to be done for all the patients from their first counselling to their last counselling. Can someone please suggest the logic

Comment: If you want to write a Python function, then you are not interested in a SQL solution.  I removed the SQL tag.

Answer (score 0):

Is following code what you were thinking?

```
log = {"Week 0" : 50, "Week 3" : 51, "Week 6" : 48}
max_weight = 0
for week in list(log):
  if log[week] > max_weight:
    max_weight = log[week]
  print("Max weight by "+week + " is "+str(max_weight))
```

This gives the following results:
[image]

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: In my database there is  a column which has the counselled dates of the patients. I will not be manually mentioning the weights for each patient over a duration of every 3 weeks as there are a lot of patients. So the function must get the max weight of the patient for the first 3 weeks, again get it for the next 3 weeks and then compare it with the previous 3 weeks. For example: 1st 21 days - max weight – 50,
next 21 days – max weight – 60,
next 21 days – max weight – 65
First it  has to get the max of 50 and 60 which is 60 and then it has to compare 60 with 65 and get the max.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding exactly what you are asking, but it seems as if the code is doing the logic you are requesting. The one thing I haven't included is retrieving the data from the database, as you haven't provided enough information on how you want the database and python function to interact. All I'm showing is the logic, and I don't understand what you want to change in that logic?

Comment: The function works fine but what i'm trying to say is that i cannot manually enter the number of weeks and the max weight at the end of every 21 days. The function must know that it has to look in the counselled dates column in the database and that it has to compare the max weight for each patient after every 3 weeks. I will not be manually entering any values as there are a lot of patients. Can you please tell me what other details you want so that i can give them to you?

Answer (score 0):

Talking about the logic,if you're looking for the max Value, it's unnecessary to test **`"week -1" against "Week -2"`** and  **`"Week -2" against "Week -3"`**.

Here is how to implement your request using pandas.
In this way you can import a sql table directly into a pandas Dataframe:

```
# import required libraries
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

# create an ODBC connection with your sql database
conn_sql = pyodbc.connect('DSN=your_dsn; UID=your_username; PWD=your_password')

# define you query
query = f'''SELECT * FROM YOUR_SQL_TABLE'''

# import your data into a Pandas dataframe called "my_dataframe"
my_dataframe = pd.read_sql(query, conn_sql)
```

Now, let me create some dummy data to show how pandas works:

```
data = {'patient': ['Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom','Tom', 'Nick','Nick','Nick','Nick','Nick'],
        'weight': [50, 51, 48, 47, 51, 80, 78, 76, 78, 75],
        'date':['10-01-2021', '20-01-2021', '20-02-2021', '30-03-2021', '20-04-2021', '20-01-2021', '22-01-2021', '23-01-2021', '20-04-2021', '20-05-2021']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# convert to date your YYYY-MM-DD
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
# create week number from date
df['week'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x.isocalendar()[1])

# first, we group by week/patient and calculate the max weigth
df_week_groupBy = df.groupby(["patient", "week"])["weight"].max()
# reset index
df_week_groupBy = df_week_groupBy.reset_index()


# create a new dataframe called "dataframe_last3week", filtering the last three weeks for every patient
dataframe_last3week = df_week_groupBy.sort_values('week', ascending = False).groupby('patient').head(3)

# group by patient and get the max weight values
results = dataframe_last3week.groupby(["patient"])["weight"].max()
```

Results are:

```
patient
Nick    78
Tom     51
```

Comment: I agree that comparing the first 3 weeks against the next 3 weeks and so on till the last counselling date is absolutely unnecessary but this is the task that i have been given. I'm a fresher and i have no idea on how to achieve this. One final question is there no other way to achieve this other than using pandas? I ask this because i don't know how to use pandas.

Comment: How your data Model is composed? Are you  working with dictionaries? With arrays ? From where are you getting Your initial data ? From Excel ? From sql ?

Comment: We work with what ever helps us achieve the required outcome. So there's no compulsion that we have to use only this or that. I am getting the initial data from sql.

Comment: Ok will try and implement this but one issue, I dont have a column called weeks in my database. All i have are dates. So how do i assign the weeks?

Comment: How your date is formatted ? YYYYMMDD ?  If your date is YYYYMMDD and if you have just 1 observation for every patient for every week, you can use my code as is. Replace  'week' with 'your_date'.

Comment: The date format is YYYY-MM-DD but there are patients who have had multiple counselings in a week. Could you please tell me what changes would i have to do in the code that you have shared  for such cases ?

Comment: I re-edit my aswer to fit your request. Now you have an example with your data model. I hope you can accept this as the correct answer. Thank you

Comment: Will implement this and check if it works. Thank you for your time and effort.